# Maximum number of records entered per day in db table

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I would like to know how can I limit the number of records entered into a db table per day. I am using Oracle database. I basically want the user to only enter 1 record per hour and throw an error if they try to go over that. Any ideas people?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save a timestamp, use a trigger

Comment: You can create a trigger before insert and check conditions as per your requirement, if it fails then you can raise a exception or handle appropriate way.

Answer (score 4):

Add two columns to the table: `user_id number, timestamp_hour date`
and

```
create unique index user_date(user_id, timestamp_hour) on your_table
```

And then:

```
insert into table values (your_columns, user_id, trunc(sysdate, 'hh'));
```

If the user tries to add a second record in the same hour will get an exception.

Comment: +1 Although I wonder if Sonic really wants to limit based on any hour interval.